# как скопировать результат выполнения команды cmd в скрипте python?

Tags: python, cmd, ос

```
import os

os.system('dir')

result = "???"
```

Comment: `result = `[`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)`(["dir"]).decode()`.

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
out = os.popen('ls').read() # or dir for windows
print(out)
```

Comment: return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 414: char
acter maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Акмаль https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033334/os-popen-read-charmap-decoding-error

Answer (score 2):

`os.system` не может получать результат. Используй это:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output('ls', shell=True).decode()
```

Comment: Мое мнение: не надо городить субпроцесс, где этого вот прям не по-зарез надо. Тут и `os.popen('...').read()` хватит ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, и так тоже пойдет :c

Comment: ага ;) хорошего дня

Comment: return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 414: char
acter maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Акмаль https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033334/os-popen-read-charmap-decoding-error

Answer (score 0):

У меня так получилось, может поможет кому.

```
import os
result = os.popen('wmic bios get serialnumber').read()
result = result.split('\n')[2]
print(result)
```